Payments Failing Using Stripe API on Production (Klarna, Afterpay, Affirm)
I am using the Stripe API to charge my customers using Klarna, Affirm, or Afterpay. Most of the charges are failing on Stripe. I frequently see a status of "Failed: This payment failed because the issuing bank declined it. Find more details on the payment timeline," or "Incomplete: The customer has not entered their payment method." All the payments go through in test mode, but in production, most of the payments fail, although a very small number do succeed. How can I fix this?

This could be numerous reasons for this. I would rather suggest to reach out to Stripe Support, so they look at your individual case: https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true
